# Effective way to compare 1d and a 2d series in python

Tags: python, string, pandas, numpy, series

I have a data frame with one column as an array of strings and the 2nd column as one string value.

```
a = pd.Series([["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"]])

b = pd.Series(["a","d","e", "c", "b"])
```

i wish to check whether b is contained in a, but i am receiving an error when running the isin function.

```
b.isin(a)
```

Any solution to this. i was particularly trying to avoid loops here, not sure if that was a good strategy based on run time.

Edit:

```
**a                          b**
["a","b","c", "d"]           a
["a","b","c", "d"]           d
["a","b","c", "d"]           e
["a","b","c", "d"]           c
["a","b","c", "d"]           b
```

the intended output is a series making row wise comparison.

```
[True True False True True]
```

Comment: What is the intended output?

Comment: I am not sure about efficiency, but `any(map(lambda x: x == b.tolist(), a))` should work;

Comment: I edited the post to include the desired output. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: `b` has 5 strings in the series but each of the rows in `a` has only 4 elements. Also, all the rows in `a` are identical. Could you say why you would expect `b` to match the first two and last two rows but not the middle row?

Comment: Ah! I see what you mean now with the latest edit. Thank you.

Comment: Simon, "a" is being checked in the array, then "d", then "e" etc. i have included that detail in the post as well now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.Series` implements the [combine](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine.html) method which you could use in the following way to find the elements in `b` that also appear in the `a` lists:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.Series([["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"]])
b = pd.Series(["a","d","e", "c", "b"])

a.combine(b, lambda a,b: b in a)
```

Output:

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4     True
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing a method which works without using loops.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.Series([["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"],["a","b","c", "d"]])
b = pd.Series(["a","d","e", "c", "b"])
[x in y for y,x in zip(a,b)]
```

... for which the output is:

```
[True, True, False, True, True]
```